# Как получить полный доступ к файловой системе андроид?

Tags: android, kotlin, root

Всем привет, я пишу приложение и мне нужно работать с файловой системой, но при команде

```
ls /data/user/0
```

я получаю вывод в консоль

```
com.google.android.gms
com.test.signal
```

где первое - почтовый клиент, а второе - мое приложение. Приложения такие как Termux и Mt Manager видят все содержимое папки без проблем. Пробовал сделать без библиотек, а также с библиотекой libsu, но результат не изменился. В чем может быть дело? Андроид 13, рут Magisk Какая дополнительная информация нужна?

Лог:[image: Лог]

Функция:

```
fun executeRootCommand(command: String): String {
    val process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su")
    val outputStream = DataOutputStream(process.outputStream)
    val inputStream = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(process.inputStream))
    val errorStream = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(process.errorStream))

    outputStream.writeBytes("$command\n")
    outputStream.writeBytes("exit\n")
    outputStream.flush()
    process.waitFor()

    val output = StringBuilder()
    var line: String?
    while (inputStream.readLine().also { line = it } != null) {
        output.append(line).append("\n")
    }
    while (errorStream.readLine().also { line = it } != null) {
        output.append(line).append("\n")
    }
    Log.d("abcde", "$command")
    Log.d("abcde", "$output")

    outputStream.close()
    inputStream.close()
    errorStream.close()

    return output.toString()
}
```

Comment: А что, собственно, вы хотите? Что вы хотели сделать и что у вас не получилось?